# PHP - DOMDocument/DOMConfiguration

Tags: php, dom, namespaces, normalization

as stated [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55012) the DOMConfiguration is not yet implemented. I need to normalize the namespaces, so that namespaces in child elements will be moved to the root element as long as prefixes are provided.

Is there any non-regexp way to do this?

Through, I am not sure, if this is even possible by [DOMConfiguration](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Core-20030226/DOM3-Core.html#core-DOMConfiguration) but I was not even able to try it as you can see.

Maybe there is a way by setting up the libxml?

Thanks.

Comment: For clarification: [`DOMDocument::normalizeDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.normalizedocument.php) will not do that by default?

Comment: you might consider shelling out to xslt

Comment: Surely you could select candidate nodes via [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and make the requisite changes w/ the standard DOM API.  Also, you can access [libxml settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) through the second argument to [DOMDocument::load](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) et al (not sure if they'll help, but that's where you can specify them).

Comment: The load-function seems to be helpful here. Thank you. However, I already changed the application to take care of the namespaces on DOM build up in a very strict manner. So a clean up is no longer required. Also: [DOMDocument::normalizeDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.normalizedocument.php) does only clean up the whitespace characters between the nodes, so that iteration through the child nodes does not require you to check for text nodes.

Comment: @user498380: Please add you solution as an answer (and accept it, yes that works ;)) - If you've got some example code feel free to add it as well if you like, even if it's only exemplary, it often says more than a thousand words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as commented I have rewritten my code, to take care of namespaces on DOM build-up. This works as follows:

```
class Foo {

  const XMLNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/';

  /**
   * Register a namespace with an optional prefix to the specified DOMElement.
   *
   * @param DOMElement $element
   * @param string $namespaceUri
   * @param string $prefix
   */
   public static final function registerNS(DOMElement $element, $namespaceUri, $prefix=null) {
     Preconditions::checkNotEmpty($namespaceUri);
     $name = "xmlns";
     if (!empty($prefix)) {
       $name .= ":$prefix";
     }
     $element->setAttributeNS(self::XMLNS, $name, $namespaceUri);
   }
}
```

Now, everytime (saying everytime here, to make things easier now) I add an element as a child of another element, I call this method and mostly provide the documentElement as the first parameter to add namespaces to the root element:

```
DOMDocument $doc = [...];
DOMElement $element = [...];
DOMElement $newChild = [...];
Foo::registerNS($doc->documentElement, $newChild->namespaceURI, $newChild->prefix);
$element->appendChild($newChild);
```